# docker-compose up fails for npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I am facing below exception while running `docker-compose up` command:

```
Creating compose_node-app_1 ... done
Attaching to compose_node-app_1
node-app_1  | 
node-app_1  | > start
node-app_1  | > node index.js
node-app_1  | 
node-app_1  | /usr/app/node_modules/assert-options/dist/src/index.js:16
node-app_1  |                 throw new Error('Option "' + a + '" is not recognized.');
node-app_1  |                 ^
node-app_1  | 
node-app_1  | Error: Option "host" is not recognized.
node-app_1  |     at assertOptions (/usr/app/node_modules/assert-options/dist/src/index.js:16:23)
node-app_1  |     at $main (/usr/app/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/main.js:194:15)
node-app_1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/app/index.js:13:12)
node-app_1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
node-app_1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
node-app_1  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
node-app_1  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
node-app_1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
node-app_1  |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
node-app_1  | npm ERR! code 1
node-app_1  | npm ERR! path /usr/app
node-app_1  | npm ERR! command failed
node-app_1  | npm ERR! command sh -c node index.js
node-app_1  | 
node-app_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
node-app_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-01-21T15_49_47_966Z-debug.log
```

Below is what I have in different files:

**docker-compose.yml**

```yml
version: '3.4'
services:
        # postgres-server:
        #         network_mode: host
        #         image: postgres
        #         restart: always
        #         environment:
        #                 POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example
        # adminer:
        #         network_mode: host
        #         image: adminer
        #         restart: always
        #         ports:
        #                 - '8080:8080'
        node-app:
                restart: on-failure
                build: .
                ports:
                        - '8089:8089'
```

**index.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {

  res.send('Welcome to K8s session')
});
app.listen(8089, hostname, ()=>{
  console.log('Listening to port 8080')
});
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "dependencies":{
    "express":"*"
  },
  "scripts":{
    "start": "node index.js"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY . .
RUN npm install --global
COPY ./package.json .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

If I normally use docker commands to build and run this container then able to do so.. but I am trying via docker-compose because would want to extend to use db.. could someone please suggest what is this host exception and how can we troubleshoot?

Thanks

Comment: try changing hostname to 0.0.0.0

Comment: tried the same as well.. still same issue.. then removed the hostname from there, then too no luck.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you are not following the [initialization steps](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/) correctly, trying to set `host` within `Initialization Options` where it does not belong, hence the error. That option is to be passed within the connection details, which is the next step, if you follow the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a docker-compose problem, it is with your usage of the `listen` command with express.

You do not need to set hostname in your `listen` call, and setting it to the loop back will just make it listen to itself, which won't work.

Remove hostname and you should be golden.

Comment: I have tried the same, removed hostname.. still the same issue.

Comment: see below is my index.js now
`
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res)=> {

  res.send('Welcome to K8s session')
});
app.listen(8089, ()=>{
  console.log('Listening to port 8080')
});
`

Comment: The error is actually coming from your postgres config, not express, as can be seen in the stack trace. It's saying that `host` is not a valid option for pg-promise.

Comment: yeah,, but m afraid in these files i have not even being using pg-promise at all for now